# How to return same value for two columns in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, hiveql

I tried this with **hive**.
There is a table with columns:

| id | key |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 123 |
| 345 | 345 |
| 123 | 123 |

The conditions are that id and key should have the same value and same length, length of the key should be 15 without duplicates

I tried

```
Select distinct id,key
from table
where id == key and length(key) = 15;
```

The desired results:

| id | key |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 123 |
| 345 | 345 |

> Error:
> The query runs too long

How do I query the table in the hive which has the same value for two columns and the same length?

Answer (score 0):

Hive may have a poor implementation for `select distinct`.  Does aggregation work?

```
Select id, key
from table
where id = key and length(key) = 15
group by id, key;
```